# Live USB - installed apps location

Tags: live-usb

I'm intrigued.

I've run a live UBUNTU 19.10 via USB on a laptop I want to cleanse of Windozes. All seems to run OK and I've downloaded a few apps (Skype / Apache). But where are these downloaded to? The PC's hard drive? USB stick? or do they just exist in memory?

Comment: @sudodus already answered this question when you asked it a few hours ago. [Live USB - installed apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213928/live-usb-installed-apps)

Comment: By default a file system is created and run from RAM.  Unless you specifically save files (or redirect folders to other storage) the downloaded apps are in the ram disk. So where they go depends on how you use the 'live' system, but yes by default it's to a ram disk, but I'd read @sudodus' response which has more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Live, Persistent and Full Installs

For a **Live** USB downloaded programs only exist in RAM. they are lost with reboot.

For a **Persistent** USB the casper-rw and/or home-rw file or partition is writable and will retain downloaded programs, (in casper-rw) or user data and settings, (in home-rw if it exists or casper-rw if not).

For a **Full install** USB, programs are saved in root partition, (/), and user data is saved in the home directory or /home partition, Just like a HDD install.

Live and Persistent USB that use a FAT32 partition, (such as UNetbootin), can be used by Linux and Windows machines for data transfer but this data is read only from the booted drive.

Grub type Persistent USB's such as mkusb, can have a NTFS or FAT partition that is read/write by Linux/Windows and the booted drive, (and by IOS, if FAT32).

Ubuntu 20.04 will likely include a writable partition for cloned installs such as Startup Disk Creator and balenaEtcher. This writable partition can easily be converted to casper-rw for persistence or NTFS for data.

Comment: Thank you - that's really interesting. It's such a cool feature. @user535733  - at the time of posting my previous question had been marked as closed as off topic (as I mentioned Mint) so didn't think any further responses would be posted.

Comment: I understand that Mint does not have a Persistence featire like Ubuntu, That for a USB that saves changes a Full install is required.